# Spring 4 @RequestMapping handling REST URL with special characters

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How does Spring 4 handle the REST URL with special character, such as #?

For example : http://localhost:8080/#/members/browse?id=1234

The following code seems not working.

Because Spring always discards everything after (including) #, and just returns the response of http://localhost:8080

Could anyone give us some help?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/#/members/browse", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public String findMembers(@RequestParam(value="id", required=false) {
   // some code
}
```

Comment: Try encoded form of `#` i.e `%23`. May be it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But @RequestMapping (value = "/%23/members/browse") seems not working, and Spring still returns the response of localhost:8080 only...

Comment: I think that everything after the # will not be send to the server, so you can't access that from Spring MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. It's a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and it's not meant to be used for routing requests on the server side.

In your browser, clicking on another anchor link like `#/members/browse?id=5678` in the same page looks for an anchor within the page and does not send a request to the server.

I think you're probably using a javascript framework such as Ember or Angular, which provide routing components to route those events on the client side and render views. See [the router documentation for Ember](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/routing/specifying-the-location-api/).